# How to prevent new line insertion when formatting sql in VS Code?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-code

I have the following snippet:

```
DECLARE @FoundDB INT = ISNULL((SELECT 1 FROM sys.databases WHERE name = @Name), 0)
```

After formatting the code I get this:

```
DECLARE @FoundDB INT = ISNULL((SELECT 1
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = @Name), 0)
```

I do not like it. I do not want the newlines. How do I control it? (Could not find anything in the settings)

Comment: AFAIK there is no default formatter for SQL files in VS code. What formatter are you using? Something like **SQL Indentator**?

Comment: I do not use any custom indentator. Whatever comes with VS Code and MSSQL extension. But there is nothing there.